# Unexpected else error in syntax?

Tags: php, json

I have the following code that keeps giving me an "unexpected else" error.  Does anyone see something that I missed that is jacking with the syntax?

```
<?php
$salesman = json_decode($invoice['salesman'], true);
if(empty($salesman)){
  for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'"/> '.$i.'<br>';
} else {
  foreach($salesman as $k => $v) {
    $i = $k+1;
    if($v == "checked" {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" checked/> '.$i.'<br>'; // if checked, check.
    } else {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'"/> '.$i.'<br>'; // if not checked, don't check.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if that's your full code, check your bracing.

Comment: the syntax is `if/else` and not `if/for`. You've a missing brace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'"/> '.$i.'<br>';
```

You are missing a `}` after the for loop.

Corrected code:

```
<?php
$salesman = json_decode($invoice['salesman'], true);
if (empty($salesman)){
    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'"/> '.$i.'<br>';
    }
} else {
    foreach($salesman as $k => $v){
        $i = $k+1;
        if ($v == "checked") {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" checked/> '.$i.'<br>'; // if checked, check.
        } else {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'"/> '.$i.'<br>'; // if not checked, don't check.
        }
    }
}
```

You also missed a ')' after `$v == "checked"` in the if-condition. Fixed that for you too.

Comment: Been staring at the code too long :P Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @Steven No problem. Tick this if this satisfied you.

Comment: Absolutely, as soon as the timer will let me